# Compare php array to mysql column

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have an array which holds numbers.

```
<?php 

$cartA = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6'];

 ?>
```

I have a mysql column that holds the numbers 4 and 6.

I want to dynamically display the $cartA array WITHOUT the numbers contained in the mysql column.
Thus I want my new array to be (or display):

```
$cartA_computer_no = ['1', '2', '3','5'];

?>
```

I have used a mysqli_fetch_assco array to fetch the results from mysql and I have used a while statement to get the values.  However I am not sure how to match and remove the numbers from the array.

This is got to be simple.  I believe either I'm over looking something or my skills are that limited as I am pretty new to this stuff.  However I been trying to figure this out for days.  Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [array_diff()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php) to get the difference between two arrays.

```
$cartA = array ('1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6');
$data_from_fetch_assoc = array ();

$result = mysqli_query ($your_query_here);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc ($result))
{
   $data_from_fetch_assoc[] = $row['cart'];
}

$cartA_computer_no = array_diff ($cartA, $data_from_fetch_assoc);
```

By the way, are you storing your numbers as string (with the single quotes) or is it just your typing?

Comment: I'm storing the numbers as strings

Comment: Got it. Btw, I have updated my answer to include information on how to push the query's result to a single array (based on your comment to @Matt Pavelle's answer).

Answer (score 0):

You should use array_diff:

```
$cartA = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6'];
$mysql_column = ['5' '6'];
$cartA_computer_no = array_diff($cartA, $mysql_column);
print_r($result);
```

Comment: When i use mysqli_fetch_assoc and a while statment i get back multiple arrays even for a single mysql column.   For example when i use a while statement and an echo row["cart"] i get back multiple arrays each array containing 1 cart value and an index. I guess my next question is how to push the mysqli_fetch_assoc results in to a single array where I could use array_diff to compare the two

Comment: you want to use mysqli_fetch_assoc($result) in a while loop - so do something like --- while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { printf ("%s (%s)\n", $row["column1"], $row["column2"]); } --- but obviously replace the printf with your logic